# Is there a way to force to krunner to run any string in konsole?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5, krunner

I have Kubuntu 19.04 installed. Is there a way to force krunner to execute a string in konsole. I'm trying to execute the string "jupyter lab" lo launch jupyter but the option to be run in konsole doesn't appear.

Of course I can just open a console by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and do it, but I want to know if there is a way to force a string to be executed as a console command from krunner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell by visiting https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/jupyter or by running

```
apt search jupyter | grep lab
```

"jupyter lab" isn't available in the 19.04 (and even 19.10) repositories.

Anyway, I ran `sudo apt install jupyter` on Kubuntu 19.04. After that,

I could type just `jupyter` in *krunner*

[image: entering jupyter in krunner]

Or I could type `jupyter notebook` in *krunner*

[image: entering jupyter notebook in krunner]

Note that I have **Command Line** to *Execute shell commands* enabled in *krunner*. To check that, click on the settings icon on the left in the *krunner* window. (But that setting is normally the default.)

[image: krunner settings]

Comment: thank you very much, but I installed jupyter with anaconda and I cant do that, however I can do it from the konsole

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of anaconda (or jupyter) but it's possible that krunner doesn't "see" *jupyter lab* because it doesn't know about it has been installed. Maybe you need to add its location to your PATH?

Comment: ah, this could be the cause, I will check it, thanks